# "'int' object is not iterable" error in for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Error in 7th line code

```
given_list2 = [5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5]

total1 = 0

b = 0

for element in given_list2[b]:
    if b <= 0:
        break
    total1 += b

print(total1)
```

Comment: print the value of `given_list2[b]` and you see that it is like you say `for i in 5: ...`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over an integer, `given_list2[b]` evaluates to the element at index b. The correct syntax to iterate through elements of a list is

```
for element in given_list2:
    if element <= 0:
        break
    total1 += element
```

or you can remove the break altogether

```
for element in given_list2:
    if element > 0:
        total1 += element
```